# How can I get variable content from a meta tag?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, meta

With XSLT I want generate the html code to a web page that can obtain from the xml design

I have this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<tagMeta>
  <metaKey>
    <keyContent>
        How to dynamically insert META Tag in an HTML document
    <keyContent>
  <metaKey>
<tagMeta>
```

And I want to getting

```
<meta name="keywords" content="I don't know whats going here to put the keyContent"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understood well...
Is this what you're looking for (/text() is optional) ?
<meta name="keywords" content="{/metaKey/keycontent/text()}"/>

Comment: Yes something like that, but I would like to do this and another page like facebook could read my meta tags, cause at the moment the solution is writing the meta on the xml file instead the xsl.

Comment: MMh, i'm not sure i got it. What i gave you, is the way in xslt to have dynamic attribute values (the AVT in the specification).
But, you seems to want it via HTTP call not in a web browser context... If this right you should design a simple webservice which will transform your document on server-side before responding to the client request.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The output you show us is not well formed XML or HTML.

Comment: What do you say about the output that isn't well formed? I think that my question is how to add meta tags when you use xml and xsl to transform the xml. Or where should I put these tags.